# after insert get primary key value in textbox

Tags: sql-server, vb6

I have 2 tables, **TableA** and **TableB**. `IMAT_PRIORITY_ID` is primary key in TableA.

How can I get the value of **IMAT_PRIORITY_ID** in a textbox after inserting into TableA?

```
strSQL1 = "INSERT TableA (IMAT_PRIORITY_ID,JOB_NO,BATCH_NO) VALUES (SQ_PRIOTITY_ID.nextval," & JOB_NO.Text & "','" & BATCH_NO.Text & "')"

With adoCommand
    .ActiveConnection = adoconn
    .CommandType = adCmdText
    .CommandText = strSQL1
    .Prepared = True
    .Execute , , adCmdText + adExecuteNoRecords
End With


strSQL1 = "INSERT TableB (ISBN_SERIAL_NO,IMAT_PRIORITY_ID,ISBN) VALUES (ISBN_SERIAL_NO.NEXTVAL,'" & IMAT_PRIORITY_ID.Text & "','" & ISBN.Text & "')"


With adoCommand
    .ActiveConnection = adoconn
    .CommandType = adCmdText
    .CommandText = strSQL1
    .Prepared = True
    .Execute , , adCmdText + adExecuteNoRecords
End With
```

Comment: Consider a stored procedure with input parameters for `ISBN_SERIAL_NO`, `IMAT_PRIORITY_ID` and `ISBN` and an output parameter for `IMAT_PRIORITY_ID`.

Comment: I hope you know that this is very sloppy code that you ought not to use in production. Use the ADO Parameter object to pass values to SQL, not string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

To get the last identity (PRIMARY KEY) generated from the insert statement you can query it as follows..

strSQL1 = "INSERT TableA (IMAT_PRIORITY_ID,JOB_NO,BATCH_NO) VALUES (SQ_PRIOTITY_ID,JOB_NO,BATCH_NO) VALUES (SQ_PRIOTITY_ID.nextval," & JOB_NO.Text & "','" & BATCH_NO.Text & "');**SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()**"

You can find more details over [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)